# JSON.deserialize for Date.class returning a wrong date

Tags: apex, class, date, deserialize

I am passing a serialized date through JavaScript using Remote Action.

In Apex I deserialize this string to a Date but the date returned is not what I am expecting. Here's my code:

```
Date newDeserializedDate = (Date) JSON.deserialize(JsDate, Date.class);
```

When I `system.debug(JsDate)` I get this: `2016-04-06`.

However when I `system.debug(newDeserializedDate )` I get `2016-01-01 00:00:00`.

Why is the date different after the desirialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `Date.valueOf()` to convert string to date value

```
String JsDate = '2016-04-06';
Date newDeserialized  = Date.valueOf(JsDate);
System.debug('newDeserialized====!'+newDeserialized);
```

Comment: `Date.valueOf()` would also return the time component with date

Comment: Thanks, wasn't that an obvious solution! Any idea what I am doing wrong with the deserialization? 

What's interesting is that I had a wrapper class that would accept a bunch of Dates and and I would  do `deserializeWrapper newWrap = (deserializeWrapper) JSON.deserialize(JsDateList, deserializeWrapper.class)` and the dates inside the wrapper were correct!

Comment: @Praveen `Date.valueOf()` will not return the time values..

Comment: @sfdcweb even i thought it wouldnt but i was surprised time being added to the date.I tried your code in  developer console this what i got:
`DEBUG|2016-04-06 00:00:00`

Comment: @Praveen time will be added as `00:00:00`  after convert into a date value it there with date but it will always be `00:00:00`  that not impact on our actual variable value.. In this ques OP doesn't have any problem with minutes value so we r good here

Comment: Ok got it @sfdcweb .